# Comparing a private object variable to a user-inputted variable

Tags: c++

I've overloaded both the `>>` and `<<` operator for pulling info from a `.dat` file and writing it to an object.

Is it possible to access the `postalCode` variable without the use of an accessor such as `getPostalCode();` and without converting `postalCode` to public? Ideally using one of the overloaded operators.

I can rewrite any of the code provided but would like to avoid adding an accessor function if possible.

We have a user input a postalCode and the program needs to return all addresses that have a matching postalCode after searching through the provided .dat file.

I'm avoiding the use of an accessor because of how the question has been phrased for the particular assignment.

```
class Address{
    public:
        void set();
        void input();
        void output();


    Address(){
        streetName = "";
        streetNr = 0;
        city = "";
        postalCode = "0000";
    }

    private:
        string streetName;
        int streetNr;
        string city;
        string postalCode;
        friend istream & operator>>(istream & in, Address & address);
        friend ostream & operator<<(ostream & out, Address & address);

};

ostream & operator<<(ostream & out, Address & address){
    out << address.streetNr << " " << address.streetName << endl;
    out << address.city << endl;
    out << address.postalCode << endl;
    out << endl;

    return out;
}

istream & operator>>(istream & in, Address & address){
    getline(in >> ws, address.streetName, '\n');
    in >> address.streetNr;
    getline(in >> ws, address.city);
    in >> address.postalCode;   

    return in;
}

int main(){

    Address temp, addresses [20];
    string pCode;
    int i = 0;

    in.open("Address.dat");
    if (in.fail()){
        cout << "Input file opening failed. \n" << endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    cout << "Postal code: ";
    cin >> pCode;
    cout << endl;

    while (in >> temp){
        if (temp.getPostalCode() == pCode){
            addresses[i] = temp;
            i++;
        }
    }
```

I understand accessing `postalCode` directly isn't possible as it will be inaccessible.

Comment: On an unrelated issue, the input and output functions doesn't match.

Comment: As for your question, why do you need to compare the postal code? What is the assignment you have? Please spend some time to read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: We have a user input a postalCode and the program needs to return all addresses that have a matching postalCode after searching through the provided .dat file.

Comment: Then the best solution is probably to include a simple "getter" function for that member.

Comment: I know this would solve the problem but I'm curious as to whether I can solve the problem without the use of one

Comment: You code as it is works for me? What exactly is your question? Please show a [mre] with the code that doesn't work.

Comment: My code works ,but I'm trying to achieve the same result without the use of an accessor function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to access the `postalCode` variable without the use of
>   an accessor such as `getPostalCode();` and without converting
>   `postalCode` to `public`?

No, you can't.  The data member is private, and there is no way to access it from outside without using a member function (or friend function).  An overloaded operator counts as a function.

> Ideally using one of the overloaded operators.

Well, if an overloaded operator doesn't count as an "accessor", then technically you can abuse overloaded operators to access the member.  For example, it is standard-conforming to do this: (in the class)

```
bool operator==(const std::string& code) const noexcept
{
    return postalCode == code;
}
```

Then you can substitute

```
temp == code
```

for `temp.getPostalCode() == code`.  This is very counter-intuitive and much inferior to using a descriptive function name.  Giving overloaded operators weird semantics is considered extremely bad practice because its sole purpose is code obfuscation.

Comment: @DamianJacobs Re-thinking of it, I think maybe `==` is better than `+` in this case.  Still much more inferior to `.getPostalCode()`.  See updated answer

Comment: I see, will then leave it as it is. Thank you again.